# How do I link to a specific iframe (not on the same page)?

Tags: iframe, hyperlink, anchor

In short; I am trying to link to an iframe. I have an iframe on one page, created by using the following code:

```
<iframe src="tng/" width="100%" height="100%" name="nr1" frameborder="0"
 scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="no"></iframe>
```

Then I have a link on another page, which uses the following code:

```
<a href="tng/surnames.php" target="nr1">specific Link</a>
```

This however, does not work, and I have no idea why!

Both pages are on the same domain, just to be clear, and I am using Joomla.

The page with the iframe is: http://www.hafdal.dk/legst/index.php/da/

The page with the link is: http://www.hafdal.dk/legst/index.php/en/

I hope someone here can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get you clearly, but I think this might solve you problem:

give your iframe an `id` attribute

```
<iframe id="myIframe" src="tng/" width="100%" height="100%" name="nr1" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto" allowtransparency="no"></iframe>
```

then suppose that the iframe is exit in "index.html" page, so your anchor hyperlink should be:

```
<a href="index.html#myIframe">go to iframe</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have edited my question to add links to the pages in question, just so the examples are clear.
I have changed the iframe name to iframe id, but I'm not sure I understand how the anchor hyperlink should be constructed, I tried <a href="tng/surnames.php#nr1">Link to surnames</a> but that didn't work.  Sorry if I'm not clear in my question!